# C++ How to store a unique pointer in a stack, and allow objects to take the pointer out of the stack (and also gain ownership)

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am struggling with a failed unit test and cannot fix the problem.

I have an interface class "ContextObject", and a class "Context" that wraps a stack of unique pointers to "ContextObjects". For the test, I also have an implementation "FooContextObject" of the interface class. Shown Below:

```
struct ContextObject {
    virtual ~ContextObject() = 0;
};
ContextObject::~ContextObject() {}

struct FooContextObject : ContextObject {
    std::string name;
    FooContextObject(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~FooContextObject() {}
};
```

The Context class is defined as follows:

```
struct Context {
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<ContextObject>> stack;
    void push(std::unique_ptr<ContextObject>&& t) { stack.push(std::move(t)); }
    std::unique_ptr<ContextObject> pop() {
        if(stack.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "Empty stack" << std::endl;
            exit(-4);
        }
        std::unique_ptr<ContextObject> ptr = std::move(stack.top());
        stack.pop();
        return std::move(ptr);
    }
    std::unique_ptr<ContextObject>& peak() { return stack.top(); }
};
```

And my test is:

```
void addToContext(Context& ctx) {
    auto obj = std::make_unique<FooContextObject>("foo");
    ctx.push(std::move(obj));
}

void useContextObject(Context& ctx) {
    ContextObject* a = ctx.pop().get();
    auto b = dynamic_cast<FooContextObject*>(a);
    std::cout << b->name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Context ctx;
    addToContext(ctx);
    useContextObject(ctx);
}
```

Can anybody let me know where I am going wrong, and help me get the code to pass the test? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by fail? What the exact symptom?

Comment: In `ContextObject* a = ctx.pop().get();`, you get a regular pointer to the `ContextObject`, but no variable to store the returned `unique_ptr` in. Wouldn't this lead to the `unique_ptr` going out of scope, and consequently, the object it points to being destroyed?

Comment: Note that `return std::move(ptr);` is unnecessary and breaks RVO, just use `return ptr;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContextObject* a = ctx.pop().get()`

Here `ctx.pop()` returns a `unique_ptr` which gets destroyed at the end of the expression because it has no owner. You should assign jt to a `unique_ptr` to keep ownership. Otherwise, you get a dangling pointer and `b->name` dereferences It, causing undefined behavior

Off topic note: consider changing the signature of `push` to

```
void push(std::unique_ptr<ContextObject> t)
```

This way it is clear to the user of the API that the object passed to push is moved-from